# Using Ramanujan's Method to Prove Larger Hypergeometric Functions

Tags: hypergeometric-function

Ramanujan had an interesting method for coming up with different hypergeometric identities. I'll provide a brief followthrough of how:

> **Ramanujan's Method of Morley's Identity:**

Start with the product of two binomials $\displaystyle(1+u)^{y+n}\left(1+1/u\right)^x$. The coefficient of $u^n$ (denoted as $[u^n]$) is given$$\displaystyle\begin{align*}[u^n](1+u)^{y+n}\left(1+\frac 1u\right)^x & =[u^n]\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom xku^{-k}\sum\limits_{r=0}^{\infty}\binom{y+n}ru^r\\ & =\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom xk[u^{n+k}]\sum\limits_{r=0}^{\infty}\binom{y+n}ru^r\\ & =\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom xk\binom{y+n}{n+k}\end{align*}$$
And we also have the coefficient of $u^n$ from $(1+u)^{x+y+n}u^{-x}$$$\displaystyle\begin{align*}[u^{n+x}](1+u)^{x+y+n} & =[u^{n+x}]\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{x+y+n}{k}u^k=\binom{x+y+n}{n+x}\end{align*}$$
Since they are equal, the hypergeometric identity follows soon afterward with a bit of manipulation.

> **Questions:**

1. Since $(1+u)^{y+n}(1+1/u)^x$ gives $_2F_1$, how would you get larger sequences, such as $_5F_4$?
2. Using that, is it possible to prove$$_5F_4\left[\begin{array}{c c}\frac 12n+1,n,-x,-y,-z\\\frac 12n,x+n+1,y+n+1,z+n+1\end{array}\right]=\frac {\Gamma(x+n+1)\Gamma(y+n+1)\Gamma(z+n+1)\Gamma(x+y+z+n+1)}{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(x+y+n+1)\Gamma(y+z+n+1)\Gamma(x+z+n+1)}$$

I've spent some time, but I have no idea what to do. I believe that the RHS can be represented by$$\binom{x+y+z+n}r$$

For $r=$ something. However, I am neither sure what the LHS is, and what $r$ is.

Comment: Alternatelly he top formulation can almost certainly be simply calculated using the Riordan transformation.  Since I have been working with these I can supply the process but it's the standard one.  For instance from BouldBk.pdf and other places. More extensive and less elementary  sequences can be done also.  Can you fill out "hypergeometric identity follows"; either by stating it or giving a reference?  Although I have to say this particular identity is nice :)

Comment: @rrogers The identity is$$_2F_1(-x,-y;n+1)=\frac {\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(x+y+n+1)}{\Gamma(x+n+1)\Gamma(y+n+1)}$$For $\text{Re }(x+y+n+1)>0$

Comment: Good!  Nice problem!  Now I see what is going on.  Basically, you think you can break up $[u^{n-m+n...}] (1+u)^{(a+b+c+...n)}$ into pieces and then set the pieces equal to the coefficient indicated?  In combinatorial functionality the only problem with this is called "diagonalization"; that is the "n" occurring in the selector and exponent.  This has a standard solution which is _sometimes_ useful, but I am not sure it's even a problem here.  BTW: the reference I gave should have been GouldBK.pdf, not BouldBk.pdf.

Comment: @rrogers Great to know! I'll do a bit more reading on this.

Comment: @rrogers My only problem is that I'm not sure how to get larger functions. The product of $(1+u)$ and $(1+1/u)$ gives the standard hypergeometric function. But how do you get $_3F_2$ or $_5F_4$?

Comment: As I see it, this is the classic "bait and switch"; my term for interchanging the order of summation.   I think I can manage a brute force translation on your hypergeometric function, or generate an inductive formula via combinatorics, or hypergeometric coefficient examination ala Zeilberger et al., or some such.   Which would you prefer?  Be aware that I have only thought about these (but think I have recognized some patterns) and I am a bit slow in my old age.  I do cheat; I have Slater's "Generalized HyperGeometric Functions"  Which has a  lot of results and what appear to be clues.

Comment: But they aren't inductive as far as I can tell.  Induction seems to be the way to climb the ladder to multiple identical (more or less) factors.  2.3.3 Dixon's theorem stands out; after some reading.

Comment: I have an inductive structure but it's entirely too general so there is probably a fault.  Would you rather wait till I fix it or peruse it yourself?  Basically it seems to evaluate $_{n+1}F_{n}((m,a),(p,b),1)=[u^{n}] (1+u)^{x+y+z...}=[u^{n}] (1+u)^{t} _{n} F_{n-1}(...u) $ which is too broad.

Comment: @rrogers Eh... Your equations didn't quite click the first time I read it. How about I wait till you fix it? :)

Comment: @rrogers There are other identities, such as$$\sum\limits_{k\geq 0}\binom{a}{l-k}\binom{b}{m-k}\binom{a+b+k}{k}=\binom{a+m}{l}\binom{b+l}{m}$$Which can be obtained with the Laurent series$$\mathrm{CT}\left(\frac x{1+y},\frac y{1+x}\right)=\mathrm{CT}\frac 1{1-xy}f(x,y)$$On $(1+y)^{-l}(1+x)^{-m}$.

Comment: I am going to put up my technique with a hypothesis for the conclusion.  I am still uncomfortable with the generality.  Unless I am mistaken,  your (y+n) above is a "red herring" and confuses the issues involved.  Replace with w=y+n and your reasoning still holds.

Comment: @rrogers Here's the PDF link to the CT that you've asked for: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Ira_Gessel/publication/256392449_Short_Proofs_of_Saalschutz%27s_and_Dixon%27s_theorems/links/5523e48e0cf2c815e07360e8/Short-Proofs-of-Saalschuetzs-and-Dixons-theorems.pdf

Comment: I've struck out so far; but have noticed that the technique you illustrated above bears a striking resemblance to Wilf's "Snake Oil method" in his book generatingfunctionology section 4.3: https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfologyLinked2.pdf

Comment: If you're actually interested in that particular 5F4() then you could look at Dougall's theorem: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DougallsTheorem.html  Slater has a proof on page 54 2.3.3.13  as a reduction of 7F_6().  I can reproduce it.  It must have a heritage from Ramanujan since it  refers to: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dougall-RamanujanIdentity.html

Comment: Are you more interested in closed forms for sums of products of binomials or closed form for Generalized Hypergeometric functions?  The Riordan array transforms give the combinatorial answers.  I can demonstrate on a particular example but am not quite organized enough to write the program/algorithm.  For instance your first one or the later one in the comments.  Be aware that the internal symbol complexity grows rapidly.  It really is a generalization of Snake Oil, Ramanujan's and CT() techniques.  I don't know but I think there are no leftover summations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is all done in the domain of the Method of Coefficients. Some of the indexing restrictions can be alleviated if needed. The results are a little tedious but simple. It's nice to have generalized techniques on hand.

---

**LEMMA 1:** For  $b>a$ and $b-a\in\mathbb{Z}$ the generating function for $\dbinom {n+ak}{m+bk}$ is

$$[t_0^n]\frac {t_0^m}{(1-t_0)^{m+1}}\left[1-\frac {t_0^{b-a}s}{(1-t_0)^b}\right]^{-1}$$

Where $s$ is the indexing variable, i.e., the $[t_0^n]$ expression is an operator transforming

$$\sum\limits_k\left(\frac {t_0^i}{(1-t_0)^j}\right)^ks^k\mapsto\sum\limits_k\binom {n+ak}{m+bk}s^k$$

***PROOF:***

$$\begin{align*}[t_0^n]\frac {t_0^m}{(1-t_0)^{m+1}}\left[1-\frac {t_0^{b-a}s}{(1-t_0)^b}\right]^{-1} & =[t_0^0]\frac {t_0^{m-n}}{(1-t_0)^{m+1}}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac {t_0^{b-a}}{(1-t_0)^b}\right)^k s^k\end{align*}$$

For a particular $k$, we evaluate the term selected by $\left[t_{0}^{0}\right]$ (the $\operatorname{CT}(\cdot)$ type of term).

$$\begin{align*}[t_0^0]\frac {t_0^{m-n}}{(1-t_0)^{m+1}}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac {t_0^{b-a}}{(1-t_0)^b}\right)^k & =[t_0^0]\frac {t_0^{m-n+(b-a)k}}{(1-t_0)^{m+bk+1}}\\ & =[t_0^0] t_0^{m-n+(b-a)k}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{+\infty}\binom {m+bk+i}{i}t_0^i\\ & =[t_0^0]\sum\limits_{i=0}^{+\infty}\binom {m+bk+i}{i}t_0^{m-n+(b-a)k+i}\end{align*}$$

Setting $m-n+(b-a)k+i=0$ gives $i=n-m-(b-a)k$, so

$$\begin{align*}\binom {m+bk+n-m-(b-a)k}{n-m-(b-a)k} & =\binom {n+ak}{n-m-(b-a)k}\\ & =\binom {n+ak}{m+bk}\end{align*}$$

---

**LEMMA 2:**

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{+\infty}\prod\limits_{i=0}^j \binom {n_i+a_ik}{m_i+b_ik}s^k=\left[\prod\limits_{i=0}^j\left([t_i^{n_i}]\frac {t_i^{m_i}}{(1-t_i)^{m_i+1}}\right)\right]\left[1-s\prod\limits_{i=0}^j\frac {t_i^{b_i-a_i}}{(1-t_i)^{b_i}}\right]^{-1}$$

***PROOF:*** This is just the iterative application of **LEMMA 1** since the terms are isolated.

---

**LEMMA 3:**

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{+\infty}\prod\limits_{i=0}^j \binom {n_i+a_ik}{m_i+b_ik}=\left[\prod\limits_{i=0}^j\left[t_i^{n_i}\right]\frac {t_i^{m_i}}{(1-t_i)^{m_i+1}}\right]\left[1-\prod\limits_{i=0}^j\frac {t_i^{b_i-a_i}}{(1-t_i)^{b_i}}\right]^{-1}$$

***PROOF:*** This is just the dropping of $s$, or setting $s=1$ if you prefer, but that has the implication of evaluation, which is not necessary since the purpose is to generate coefficients not function values.

---

**EXAMPLE 4:** Note that

$$\begin{align*}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{+\infty}\binom xk\binom {y+n}{n+k} & =[t_0^x][t_1^{y+n}]\frac {t_0^0}{1-t_0}\frac {t_1^n}{(1-t_1)^{n+1}}\left(1-\frac {t_0^1}{1-t_0}\frac {t_1^1}{1-t_1}\right)^{-1}\\ & =[t_0^0][t_1^0]\frac {t_0^{-x}}{1-t_0}\frac {t_1^{-y}}{(1-t_1)^{n+1}}\left(1-\frac {t_0^1}{1-t_0}\frac {t_1^1}{1-t_1}\right)^{-1}\\ & =[t_0^0][t_1^0]\frac {t_0^{-x} t_1^{-y}}{(1-t_1)^n}\frac 1{1-t_0-t_1}\\ & =[t_0^0][t_1^0]\frac {t_0^{-x} t_1^{-y}}{(1-t_1)^{n+1}}\frac 1{1-t_0/(1-t_1)}\\ & =[t_0^0][t_1^0]\frac {t_0^{-x} t_1^{-y}}{(1-t_1)^{n+1}}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac {t_0}{1-t_1}\right)^i\\ & =[t_0^0][t_1^0]\sum\limits_{i=0}^{+\infty}\frac {t_0^{i-x} t_1^{-y}}{(1-t_1)^{n+i+1}}\end{align*}$$

Evaluating the $t_0$ term, we have that $i=x$. Thus, we get

$$[t_1^0]\frac {t_1^{-y}}{(1-t_1)^{n+x+1}}=[t_1^0]\sum\limits_{j=0}^{+\infty}\binom {x+n+j}{j} t_1^{j-y}$$

Setting $j-y=0$ gives $j=y$.

$$\binom {x+y+n}y=\binom {x+y+n}{x+n}$$

Which is your first answer.

**Remark:** If wanted I can carry out the three term evaluation in the comments but it gets a little tedious.  This was a good problem for me because I have been meaning to organize this for ages.

Comment: I've gone ahead and touched up your $\LaTeX$, let me know if I've made any errors while copying over

Comment: I'm reviewing this method and trying to apply it for larger binomial coefficient sequences. How would you use this to prove something like [this identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2381429/proving-this-infinite-sum-of-a-product-of-three-binomials-sum-limits-s-bino?noredirect=1&lq=1)? I am having a difficult time reducing $(1-t_0)(1-t_1)(1-t_2)-t_0t_2$ into a difference of binomials purely in terms of $u$, $1-v$, and $1-w$

Comment: Oops, the $u$, $1-v$, and $1-w$ in my last comment were supposed to be $t_0$, $1-t_1$, and $1-t_2$ respectively

Comment: @FrankW I am looking at, and recalling this problem.  It's a little strange :)  I have made several attempts but apparently didn't think they were adequate.  I will think some more about this problem; 5F4.  If you want I will supply a link to my last one go around; it's too raw to post :)
Basically multiple lower F()'s by (1+u)^z  and the relationship might follow.   Or vice versa.  This approach relied on Slater a bit; his Slater Appendix I Eq: 1.7
YMWV :)

Comment: Yes, can you send me a link to your last attempt? I probably missed something when I tried

Comment: @FrankW  I will do it in a  couple of hours/tomorrow.  I realized during dinner that I didn't answer your question about t_o, t_i, t_2 though.  It seems obvious now, but to me, that's not a good thing to take to the bank :)   Something like: "Aha!  I found the last bug" ;) :)

Comment: No worries, take your time, I'm not particularly bright so it's probably something simple :)

Comment: @FrankW For anybody who is interested in somewhat relevant references:
https://www.mdpi.com/2075-1680/7/2/38
https://ia902804.us.archive.org/11/items/pli.kerala.rare.37877/pli.kerala.rare.37877.pdf  (section § 7.3)
and, of  course, 
Slater: Generalized Hypergeometric Functions: 9780521090612: Slater, Lucy Joan:
and 
Luke:

Comment: @Frank  FYI:  Here is an earlier exposition/answer that details the link to 2F1(); the last section of the answer.  I am trying to figure out how I missed that, when I had spent effort on exactly that.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2189765/ramanujans-proof-for-morleys-hypergeometric-identity

Comment: Yeah, I tried that method for larger cases. I was able to prove the ${}_3F_2$ case, but haven't found any sum for the ${}_4F_3$ case