# Proving this infinite sum of a product of three binomials: $\sum\limits_{s}\binom{n+s}{k+l}\binom ks\binom ls=\binom nk\binom nl$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

> **Question:** How do you prove$$\sum\limits_{s}\binom{n+s}{k+l}\binom ks\binom ls=\binom nk\binom nl$$

I'm just not sure where to begin. I tried writing both sides as the coefficient of $x^n$ of the expansion of a binomial. But obviously, that doesn't fit the right-hand side because it's the product of two binomials.

I'm guessing that we'll need the multinomial theorem. Is that correct? Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: You really don't need to think of it as an infinite sum, since only finitely many values are non-zero.

Comment: [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity) and its proofs might provide some insight.

Answer (score 4):

$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,\,s\,\left( { \le \,k} \right)} {\left( \matrix{
  n + s \cr 
  k + l \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  k \cr 
  s \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  l \cr 
  s \cr}  \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,\,s\,\left( { \le \,k} \right)} {\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,\,j\,\left( { \le \,k + l} \right)} {\left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  k + l - j \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  s \cr 
  j \cr}  \right)} \left( \matrix{
  k \cr 
  s \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  l \cr 
  s \cr}  \right)}  =  \;(1) \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,\,s\,\left( { \le \,k} \right)} {\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,\,j\,\left( { \le \,k + l} \right)} {\left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  k + l - j \cr}  \right)} \left( \matrix{
  k \cr 
  j \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  k - j \cr 
  s - j \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  l \cr 
  s \cr}  \right)}  = \; (2)  \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,\,s\,\left( { \le \,k} \right)} {\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,\,j\,\left( { \le \,k + l} \right)} {\left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  k + l - j \cr}  \right)} \left( \matrix{
  k \cr 
  j \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  k - j \cr 
  k - s \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  l \cr 
  s \cr}  \right)}  =  \; (3) \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,\,j\,\left( { \le \,k + l} \right)} {\left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  k + l - j \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  k \cr 
  j \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  k + l - j \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)}  =  \; (4)\cr 
  &  = \left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,\,j\,\left( { \le \,k + l} \right)} {\left( \matrix{
  n - k \cr 
  l - j \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  k \cr 
  j \cr}  \right)}  =  \;(5) \cr 
  &  = \left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  l \cr}  \right) \; (6) 
\quad \left| \matrix{  \;l,k \in \mathbb{N_0}  \hfill \cr   \;n \in \mathbb{C} \hfill \cr}  \right.
\cr} 
$$

where:
 - (1) inverse convolution
 - (2) *Trinomial revision* on 2nd and 3rd binomial
 - (3) *Symmetry* on 3rd ($k-j$ is non-negative because of the 2nd)
 - (4) convolution in $s$
 - (5) *Trinomial revision* on 1st and 3rd binomial
 - (6) convolution in $j$

Answer (score 3):

We seek to simplify

$$\sum_s {n+s\choose k+l} {k\choose s} {l\choose s}.$$

The substitution $s = t + k+l-n$ yields

$$\sum_t {t+k+l\choose k+l} {k\choose t + k+l-n} {l\choose t+k+l-n}.$$

Working with the assumption that  the parameters are positive integers
we find that from the first binomial coefficient we get that for it to
be non-zero we must have $t\ge  0$ or $t\lt -(k+l).$ Note however that
in the latter case the two remaining coefficients vanish, which leaves
$t\ge 0.$ Re-writing we find

$$\sum_{t\ge 0} {t+k+l\choose k+l} {k\choose n-l-t} {l\choose n-k-t}.$$

We introduce  integral represenations  for the two  right coefficients
that also enforce the  fact that $t\le n-l$ and $t\le  n-k$ so that we
may then let $t$ range to infinity. We use

$${k\choose n-l-t} =
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon_1}
\frac{1}{z^{n-l-t+1}} (1+z)^k
\; dz$$

as well as

$${l\choose n-k-t} = 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|v|=\epsilon_2}
\frac{1}{v^{n-k-t+1}} (1+v)^l
\; dv.$$

We then get for the sum (no convergence issues here)

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon_1}
\frac{1}{z^{n-l+1}} (1+z)^k
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|v|=\epsilon_2}
\frac{1}{v^{n-k+1}} (1+v)^l
\sum_{t\ge 0} {k+l+t\choose k+l} v^t z^t
\; dv\; dz.
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon_1}
\frac{1}{z^{n-l+1}} (1+z)^k
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|v|=\epsilon_2}
\frac{1}{v^{n-k+1}} (1+v)^l
\frac{1}{(1-vz)^{k+l+1}}
\; dv\; dz.$$

We see that  this vanishes when $n\lt  k$ or $n\lt l$,  which we label
case A.  Case B  is that  $n\ge k,l.$ We  evaluate the  inner integral
using the fact that residues sum to zero. With this in mind we write

$$\frac{(-1)^{k+l+1}}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon_1}
\frac{1}{z^{n+k+2}} (1+z)^k
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|v|=\epsilon_2}
\frac{1}{v^{n-k+1}} (1+v)^l
\frac{1}{(v-1/z)^{k+l+1}}
\; dv\; dz.$$

We thus require for the pole at $v=1/z$

$$\frac{1}{(k+l)!}
\left(\frac{1}{v^{n-k+1}} (1+v)^l\right)^{(k+l)}$$

which is (apply Leibniz)

$$\frac{1}{(k+l)!}
\sum_{q=0}^{k+l} {k+l\choose q} 
(-1)^q {n-k+q\choose q} \frac{q!}{v^{n-k+1+q}}
\\ \times {l\choose k+l-q} (k+l-q)! (1+v)^{l-(k+l-q)}
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^{k+l}
(-1)^q {n-k+q\choose q} \frac{1}{v^{n-k+1+q}}
{l\choose k+l-q} (1+v)^{q-k}.$$

Evaluate at $v=1/z$ to get

$$\sum_{q=0}^{k+l}
(-1)^q {n-k+q\choose q} z^{n-k+1+q}
{l\choose k+l-q} \frac{(1+z)^{q-k}}{z^{q-k}}.$$

Substituting  this into  the integral  in  $z$ and  flipping the  sign
yields

$$(-1)^{k+l} \sum_{q=0}^{k+l}
(-1)^q {n-k+q\choose q}
{l\choose k+l-q} {q\choose k}.$$

Now we have

$${q\choose k} {n-k+q\choose q} =
\frac{(n-k+q)!}{k! \times (q-k)! \times (n-k)!}
= {n\choose k} {n-k+q\choose n}$$

and we obtain

$$(-1)^{k+l} {n\choose k} \sum_{q=0}^{k+l}
(-1)^q {l\choose k+l-q} {n-k+q\choose n}
\\ = {n\choose k} \sum_{q=0}^{k+l}
(-1)^q {l\choose q} {n+l-q\choose n}
\\ = {n\choose k} [w^n] \sum_{q=0}^{k+l}
(-1)^q {l\choose q} (1+w)^{n+l-q}
\\ = {n\choose k} [w^n] (1+w)^{n+l} \sum_{q=0}^{k+l}
(-1)^q {l\choose q} \frac{1}{(1+w)^q}
\\ = {n\choose k} [w^n] (1+w)^{n+l}
\left(1-\frac{1}{1+w}\right)^l
\\ = {n\choose k} [w^n] w^l (1+w)^{n}
= {n\choose k} {n\choose n-l} = {n\choose k} {n\choose l}.$$

This is the claim, which we proved for case B.

**Remark.** To  be perfectly rigorous  we also  need to show  that the
contribution from the residue at infinity is zero. We find

$$\mathrm{Res}_{v=\infty} \frac{1}{v^{n-k+1}} (1+v)^l
\frac{1}{(1-vz)^{k+l+1}}
\\ = - \mathrm{Res}_{v=0} \frac{1}{v^2} v^{n-k+1} \frac{(1+v)^l}{v^l}
\frac{1}{(1-z/v)^{k+l+1}}
\\ = - \mathrm{Res}_{v=0} \frac{1}{v^2} v^{n-k-l+1} (1+v)^l
\frac{v^{k+l+1}}{(v-z)^{k+l+1}}
\\ = - \mathrm{Res}_{v=0} v^{n} (1+v)^l
\frac{1}{(v-z)^{k+l+1}} = 0$$

and the check goes through.

Comment: This approach is with respect to this specific binomial identity as cool as it is an overkill! :-) Big fat (+1)

Comment: Observation registered. What I find interesting here is that the double integral has a very nice symmetry which however we could not exploit during evaluation. Solving this one by taking advantage of the symmetry seems like an interesting challenge.

Comment: I agree, but I have no idea how to make good use of it. An interesting aspect right at the beginning was your first substitution. It  was presumably intended to *synchronise* upper and lower part of the first binomial coefficient $\binom{t+k+l}{k+l}$ - clever, as there was no negative side effect on the other binomial coefficients.

Comment: Kind of you to notice. Since you are asking, what happened here was I did not think of this substitution at first and evaluated the sum as given, which gave me the double integral, which I expanded into a sum, which in turn gave the substituted version. I then realized I could omit the entire first part of the calculation and keep only the substitution.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}
\sum_s \color{blue}{\binom {n+s}{k+l}}\binom ks\binom ls
&=\sum_s\color{blue}{\sum_j\binom n{k+j}} \color{green}{\binom ks}
\underbrace{\binom ls\color{blue}{\binom s{l-j}}}
_{=\color{orange}{\binom l{l-j}\binom{j}{s-l+j}}}
\\
&=\sum_j\binom n{k+j}\color{orange}{\binom l{l-j}}
\underbrace{\sum_s \color{green}{\binom k{k-s}}\color{orange}{\binom j{s-l+j}}}_{*=\binom{k+j}{k-l+j}=\color{pink}{\binom{k+j}{l}}}\\
&=\sum_j \binom l{l-j}
\underbrace{\binom n{k+j} \qquad \color{pink}{\binom {k+j}l}}
_{=\color{magenta}{\binom nl\binom {n-l}{k+j-l}}}\\
&=\color{magenta}{\binom nl}
\underbrace{\sum_j \binom l{l-j}
\color{magenta}{\binom{n-l}{k+j-l}}}_{*=\color{red}{\binom nk}}\\
&=\color{red}{\binom nk \binom nl}
\end{align}$$
* using the [Vandermonde Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity).